# Installation xdebud on sublime 3 error

Tags: php, xdebug, fedora-21

I'm trying install xdebug on sublime3. I installed with package control and added the following code in php.info:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

But it doesn't even list in the info.php. The documentation says to add

```
 zend_extension="/wherever/you/put/it/xdebug.so"
```

But I can't find the location of `.so` in the Fedora that I'm using, and I guess it's because I downloaded it with package control. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can edit your question. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Answer (score 0):

Run `php -i | grep extension_dir` in your terminal to see where the extensions for PHP are installed.

Comment: Thanks man, I could realize that I should has installed the xdebug.so itself, and not just the sublime xdebug plugin.